# How to present tabular data using Python (and maybe pandas?)

Tags: python, pandas, tabular

I want to create a table (say in a Jupyter notebook) based on a function and the product of two lists. To give a concrete example, assuing my data is:

```
rows = [1, 2, 3, 4]
columns = [100, 200, 300]
f = x + y
```

I expect something like

```
    100 200 300
1   101 201 301
2   102 202 302
3   103 203 303
4   104 204 304
```

My current solution is:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product, zip_longest

# this is from the package more-itertools
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

f = lambda row: row[0] + row[1]
results = (
  pd.DataFrame(grouper(product(rows, columns), len(columns)), columns=columns, index=rows)
 .applymap(f)
)
```

It feels very convoluted and I feel there is a better way of doing it

Comment: Removed `jupyter-notebook` tag as it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) addition.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(data=np.add.outer(rows, columns),
             index=rows,
             columns=columns)

   100  200  300
1  101  201  301
2  102  202  302
3  103  203  303
4  104  204  304
```

Comment: You attached old documentation link in the answer, here is v.1.18 link [`numpy.ufunc.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer). Nice answer +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use convert `rows` and `columns` to NumPy array and use [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html) here.

```
rows = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
columns = np.array([100, 200, 300])

data = rows[:,None] + columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= columns,index=rows)
df
   100  200  300
1  101  201  301
2  102  202  302
3  103  203  303
4  104  204  304
```